# One word riddle: Vowel in the middle

Tags: word

> I am a simple word.
>   To me, add a single letter, and it will make the opposite of me.
>   To me, add a different letter, and it will create my homophone.
>   To me, add a different letter, and I won't be so good.

Can you guess?

Comment: For clarification, is each line adding on to the prior one, or is it all from the original word?

Comment: All from the original word. That is why I said "To me " every time

Comment: If the title is meant to be a constraint to the type and location of the letter addition, may I strongly recommend you make that abundantly clear.  Right now the puzzle *per se* only requires adding a single letter, vowel or consonant, at any place in the word - which may be your intent, but given the title I suspect not.

Comment: @Rubio I think the title only refers to "me" the original and target word of the riddle.

Comment: If that's the case, there are likely to be *many* good solutions - so I rather hope it's meant to be more restrictive.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Could it be

> our

Add a single letter, it will make the opposite of me

> Your - not ours, but yours

Add a different letter, it will create my homophone

> Hour

Add a different letter, and I won't be so good

> Sour

And with the title and intro:

> It is a simple word with a vowel in the middle!

Comment: I think this answer is good (certainly a better fit than my own) but I think the homophone is very accent dependent!

Comment: I suspect that either this IS the answer, or the answer is not much of a better fit

Comment: @micsthepick I think there are likely several possible answers. Though I would argue my latest attempt is an even better fit :)

Comment: That was wonderful

Answer (score 6):

Second attempt (paying attention to title)

> Led

Add a single letter, it will make the opposite of me

> Fled (Opposite of leading is fleeing)

Add a different letter, it will create my homophone

> Lead

Add a different letter, and I won't be so good

> Bled (Bleeding typically is not good)

Original attempt

> Ad (as in advertisement)

Add a single letter, it will make the opposite of me

> Fad (weakest link for sure)

Add a different letter, it will create my homophone

> Add (addition)

Add a different letter, and I won't be so good

> Bad (not good, obviously I worked backwards here)

Comment: Vowel in the middle???

Comment: I suppose it depends how you define middle. To be honest I had overlooked the title :)

Comment: Great second attempt

Answer (score 4):

An alternative answer to those already given

> Nob = a person of high social position

To me, add a single letter, and it will make the opposite of me.

> Noob = a person who is inexperienced in a particular sphere or activity, especially computing or the use of the Internet.

To me, add a different letter, and it will create my homophone.

> Knob

To me, add a different letter, and I won't be so good.

> Snob = a person with an exaggerated respect for high social position or wealth who seeks to associate with social superiors and looks down on those regarded as socially inferior.

Title

> It has a vowel in the middle.

Comment: another great answer